# Full example of nginx configuration file for a localhost on OSX 10.9.2

Tags: php, nginx, localhost, osx-mavericks

I installed the nginx 1.4.6, mysql 5.6.16 and php 5.6.0-alpha.2 on a OSX 10.9.2 using homebrew and used the default nginx.conf file and changed the parameters to setup a virtual host. However, I received different types of errors from yesterday and changed the config file many times, but end of with nothing :). Below is the information from my terminal using `nginx -V`:

`nginx version: nginx/1.4.6
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-ipv6 --sbin-path=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/bin/nginx --with-cc-opt='-I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.34/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1f/include' --with-ld-opt='-L/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.34/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1f/lib' --conf-path=/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/client_body_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/scgi_temp --http-log-path=/usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log --with-http_gzip_static_module`

I would be very appreciative if you can send a full example of nginx.conf file to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry if not being clear enough, I'll submit another post with more details and errors.

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find the code that finally worked for three different websites on ports 80, 90 and 100.

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
error_log /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/error.log;
pid       /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /usr/local/etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include       /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    access_log    /usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        access_log  /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/localhost.access.log  combined;

        location / {
            root   /Users/apia/Websites/jackpot;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /Users/apia/Websites/jackpot;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /Users/apia/Websites/jackpot$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen       90;
        server_name  localhost;
        access_log  /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/localhost.access.log  combined;

        location / {
            root   /Users/apia/Websites/fiftyfirst;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /Users/apia/Websites/fiftyfirst;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /Users/apia/Websites/fiftyfirst$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen       100;
        server_name  localhost;
        access_log  /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/localhost.access.log  combined;

        location / {
            root   /Users/apia/Websites/sunshine;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /Users/apia/Websites/sunshine;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /Users/apia/Websites/sunshine$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }    
}
```